# Use .Formula to Sum a Changing Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill out a table by summing the first "x" number of values then the next "x" number of values.

Essentially this:
=SUM(Ax:Ay) where x and y are the row numbers

```
Sheets(1).Range("B"+i).Formula = "=SUM(A" & x & ":A" & y & ")"
```

Here is what my actual code looks like:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim slider_val As Long
Dim output_tbl As ListObject
Dim data_tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim start As Long
Dim finish As Long

Set data_tbl = Sheets("Data").ListObjects("DataTable")
Set output_tbl = Sheets("Slider").ListObjects("OutputTable")
slider_val = Sheets("Slider").Range("A5").Value

start = 2

    For i = 1 To 12

        finish = start + slider_val

        Sheets("Slider").Range("B" & j).Formula = "=SUM(Data!K" & start & ":K" & finish & ")"

        j = j + 1
        start = finish + 1

    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I get the error "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I try to run this code.

Comment: And use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate

Comment: Dim your `start` and `finish` variables as long. No need to convert them to strings

Comment: ^ All your `CStr` and `CInt` lines are unnecessary.

Comment: Ah didn't know that. Thanks. Also, changed the "+" to "&" and am now getting an "application defined or object defined" error

Comment: Then change the error in the OP as it no longer throws that error.

Comment: what are the values of `start` and `finish`? Probably one or both are 0. **EDIT**: `j` is **0**.

Comment: ^ you need to assign values to `start` and `finish` _before_ your loop

Comment: start = 2 and changes based on a slider value. I can include the rest of the code in the post

Comment: Might be useful to see the initial values for `start`, `finish`, `i` and `j`

Comment: Move `j = j + 1` before the `Sheets` line, otherwise you have `B0` as your cell. Or better, just use `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, the problem was that I had not defined "j" yet.

Comment: Why use `j`? Use `i`.

Comment: The actual application is going to be a little more complicated. This is the rough draft.